# Why wasn't Sacha Baron Cohen arrested for interrupting CPAC 2020?

Tags: united-states

> Comedian Sacha Baron Cohen attended CPAC dressed as President Trump
> while filming his latest   movie ***Borat Subsequent Moviefilm***.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_Political_Action_Conference#Sacha_Baron_Cohen_interruption)

Why wasn't Sacha Baron Cohen arrested for interrupting CPAC 2020?

Comment: Arrested for what? Interrupting a speech is not a crime.

Comment: Trespassing is a crime.

Comment: @user6726 Depends if he had permission to be in the Gaylord National Resort & Convention Center

Comment: Why the thumbs down? it's a legitimate question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The media purports that he was let through security, thus he had permission to be present. There is no evidence that he made a false statement to the effect that he was Trump, or in any way gained unlawful access. It is not at all clear what person in authority told him to leave, but there is no evidence that, permission to be present having been rescinded he remained at the venue. There is no evidence that he did anything that constituted "interrupting" or "disrupting" the event, and it is plainly evident that the disruption comes from the audience who decided to start chanting. Since he did not interrupt the speech and did not trespass, all they could do was remove him from the venue. Courts in the US do not hold that the peaceful presence of an opponent at a political event constitutes "instigation" or "disruption".